# React Native Android api call returning 'Error: Network Error' to local database

Tags: typescript, api, react-native, axios

Using axios and promise to call a local database api I am unable to reach the endpoint no matter what I try, I continually get a 'Error: Network Error' console feedback without any message as to what the problem really is.

I am providing the correct endpoint by using the android systems localhost `https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/[endpoint]`, when i go to this endpoint in the chrome browser it shows the correct JSON but the application doesnt appear to be able to get the data.

Internet permissions are turned on for the manifest.

```js
axios
    .get('https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/[endpoint]')
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: See the logcat of Android Studio for complete error. Have you tested on another link?? like google.com for example

Comment: We have tested the JSONplaceholder website and it accurately resolves the promise and can log the data that is responded.

Comment: you can try `console.log(typeof response)` or `console.assert(response)`

Comment: @hongdevelop its not a matter of the typeof, the connection is not going through at all. The React Native application cannot connect to the local database that is running so that I can hit the endpoint of the API. I have tried to run `adb reverse tcp:5001 tcp:5001`to make the emulator use that port but that doesnt appear to work

Answer (score 0):

So the working way to get the emulator was using ngrok and then running `ngrok http https://localhost:[port] -host-header="localhost:[port]"`

this forwarded the localhost port to a website that can be called.